# What does @ mean in elastic search documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

My question is: "What does the @ mean in elastic search documents?" @timestamp automatically gets created along with @version. Why is this and what's the point?

Here is some context... I have a web app that writes logs to files. Then I have logstash forward these logs to elastic search. Finally, I use Kibana to visualize everything.

Here is an example of one of the documents in elastic search:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2018.02.17",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "0PknomEBajxXe2bTzwxm",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-02-17T05:06:13.362Z",
    "source": "source",
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "message",
    "env": "development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-02-17T05:06:13.362Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1518843973362
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ fields are usually ones generated by Logstash as metadata ones, @timestamp being the value that the event was processed by Logstash.  Similarly @version is also being added by Logstash to denote the version number of the document.

Here is the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata).

Comment: What about the "fields" key which contains @timestamp again. Is this logstash adding things again, elastic search, or something else?

Comment: Yes its also part of Logstash 1.5. Here is the reference https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata

Answer (score 1):

The `@` field is the metadata created for Logstash. It is part of the data itself.

More info is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target).